# How to detect first launch in react-native

Tags: react-native

What is a good way to detect the first and initial launch of an react-native app, in order to show an on-boarding/introductory screen ?

Comment: Consider using `AsyncStorage`: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.37/docs/asyncstorage.html

Comment: But due to the fact that AsyncStorage is ~async~, the response is returned through a callback, which I can't make the view wait for. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: you can play with `View` state, lets say you can show some `ActivityIndicator` until LocalStorage' responses , then hide the ActivityIndicator by something like `this.setState({shouldShowIndicator: false})`

Comment: Consider about using `Realm`: http://realm.io/
I have used `Realm` to show several pages just for the first app launch. So this is working pretty perfect.

Comment: wouldn't asyncStorage be cleared on clearing app Data?

Comment: @JonathanStellwag how did you manage it can you write an answer below

Comment: @ErenTüfekçi the only difference between a `Realm` and an `AsyncStorage` solution (like the accepted answer below) is the library itself. You need to save a Token (like alreadyLaunched: boolean) and check for the value in the component you want the specify. If you have problems implementing `Realm` consider creating a question that specifies your problem

Comment: I would use Realm Database instead of AsyncStorage to optimize performance. In the end, you will still be able to meet the objective but you will notice it in the speed with which your application loads.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Your logic should follow this:

```js
class MyStartingComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {firstLaunch: null};
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        AsyncStorage.getItem("alreadyLaunched").then(value => {
            if(value === null){
                 AsyncStorage.setItem('alreadyLaunched', 'true'); // No need to wait for `setItem` to finish, although you might want to handle errors
                 this.setState({firstLaunch: true});
            }
            else{
                 this.setState({firstLaunch: false});
            }}) // Add some error handling, also you can simply do this.setState({fistLaunch: value === null})
    }

    render(){
       if(this.state.firstLaunch === null){
           return null; // This is the 'tricky' part: The query to AsyncStorage is not finished, but we have to present something to the user. Null will just render nothing, so you can also put a placeholder of some sort, but effectively the interval between the first mount and AsyncStorage retrieving your data won't be noticeable to the user.
       }else if(this.state.firstLaunch === 'true'){
           return <FirstLaunchComponent/>
       }else{
           return <NotFirstLaunchComponent/>
       }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: does not work for me... It shows it every time. Seem a general Problem with AsyncStorage. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18372

Comment: problem was that true is not a string. Surround true with quotes then it works

Comment: `JSON.stringify` everything before putting it in async storage. `JSON.parse` after retrieving from storage

Comment: @martinarroyo This approach will result in an app update which includes this code also being "seen" as a `firstLaunch`. I just bumped into this issue.

Comment: I got a warning using this code:
"java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String"

Comment: @FabioDev This might have changed internally in RN. You can always use a string to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 28):

I made some adjustments to martinarroyo's suggestion. `AsyncStorage.setItem` should set a string value and not a bool.

```js
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
    
const HAS_LAUNCHED = 'hasLaunched';

function setAppLaunched() {
  AsyncStorage.setItem(HAS_LAUNCHED, 'true');
}

export default async function checkIfFirstLaunch() {
  try {
    const hasLaunched = await AsyncStorage.getItem(HAS_LAUNCHED);
    if (hasLaunched === null) {
      setAppLaunched();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

This function can then be imported wherever you need it. Note that you should render null (or something else clever) while waiting for the async function to check AsyncStorage.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import checkIfFirstLaunch from './utils/checkIfFirstLaunch';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isFirstLaunch: false,
      hasCheckedAsyncStorage: false,
    };
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    const isFirstLaunch = await checkIfFirstLaunch();
    this.setState({ isFirstLaunch, hasCheckedAsyncStorage: true });
  }

  render() {
    const { hasCheckedAsyncStorage, isFirstLaunch } = this.state;

    if (!hasCheckedAsyncStorage) {
      return null;
    }

    return isFirstLaunch ?
      <Text>This is the first launch</Text> :
      <Text>Has launched before</Text>
    ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you not use a boolean?

Comment: Because it is a key value string store, and the AsyncStorage docs specifies that the value should be a string [https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#setitem](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#setitem). I am not 100% sure, but I assume that if you try to store a boolean, it will be converted to a string. When fetching it later with `getItem`, I assume that it won't automatically be converted back to a boolean.

Comment: I think a clever thing to render while waiting for the async function to check AsyncStorage would be a loading animation.

Comment: @Fl4v `AsyncStorage` returns so quickly there's no need for a loading indicator. Just because it's `async` it doesn't necessarily mean it'll take long to resolve/reject :)

Comment: @Bataleon it is always useful (not necessary, I agree) to wait while loading/fetching.

Answer (score 7):

**In 2022**: Note that AsyncStorage from react-native is already deprecated.
Use [react-native-async-storage/async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage) instead.

Custom hook:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

async function checkIfFirstLaunch() {
  try {
    const hasFirstLaunched = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@usesr_onboarded");
    if (hasFirstLaunched === null) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}

const useGetOnboardingStatus = () => {
  const [isFirstLaunch, setIsFirstLaunch] = useState(false);
  const [isFirstLaunchIsLoading, setIsFirstLaunchIsLoading] = useState(true);

  React.useEffect(async () => {
    const firstLaunch = await checkIfFirstLaunch();
    setIsFirstLaunch(firstLaunch);
    setIsFirstLaunchIsLoading(false);
  }, []);

  return {
    isFirstLaunch: isFirstLaunch,
    isLoading: isFirstLaunchIsLoading,
  };
};

export default useGetOnboardingStatus;
```

Usage:

```js
import useGetOnboardingStatus from "../../utils/useGetOnboardingStatus";

const { isFirstLaunch, isLoading: onboardingIsLoading } =
    useGetOnboardingStatus();
```

As Eirik Fosse mentioned: You can use onboardingIsLoading to return null while waiting for the response.